# Importing a blender model into a DirectX 11.2 C++ application

Tags: c++, import, blender, directx-11

I'm new to DirectX applications, with a decent knowledge of C++ and some experience in working with Blender. So for starters i would like to know how could i import, say, a UV sphere from Blender into a DirectX 11.2 C++ application. I'm using november edition compiler. Is there a tutorial for working with Blender models in DirectX applications that is up to date? Because i read that the .X format is not supported anymore after DirectX 10, and i need to use it in a DirectX 11.2 enviroment. I'm pretty much clueless about what to do and in what direction to go, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can try using the built-in Visual Studio 2012/2013 mesh exporter to CMO. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh972446.aspx). The [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) supports loading CMOs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you 'just' want to display some 3D objects using native DirectX there is no other way than doing all the initialization stuff, writing a file loader for some kind of format that Blender is able to export and setting up a respective render pipeline. Indeed the way is long until you can see your Blender model in your own application. But if you intend to write your own graphics engine eventually it is a way you have to take. If this is not your goal I recommend you to use an open source 3D engine of your choice.

I used a very good online tutorial on a web page which unfortunately does not exist any more and of course the MSDN libraray to learn about DirectX 11. You can still find these tutorials at an [internet archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20140701085652/http://rastertek.com/tutdx11.html). Additionally I found another [tutorial](http://www.walkerb.net/blog/dx-1/) which seems to look good at a first glance.

If you don't need to do very special things which Blender must write into the file you are exporting, I suggest using the .obj format since it is easy to understand and to load.

By chance I'm writing my own graphics engine in the moment. So if you have any further questions concerning this topic feel free to contact me.

Comment: I am not creating an engine, i just need to load some 3D models into the app, so could you maybe recommend a good open source program like Blender in which i could export an .obj model which can be easily imported in Visual Studio DirectX 11 app? Any tutorial would also be helpful for loading .obj models. Thank you for your time

Comment: Blender is able to export a model directly as an .obj file. Use File->Export->Wavefront .OBJ or something like that (I do not have Blender installed here so I don't know the exact caption of the menu entry). You can find lots of information on how to load .obj files using Google. I did a quick search and found this tutorial: [link](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/) But favor std::fstream over scanf().

Comment: thank you. I will look into it, if i have any more questions, i can freely ask?

Answer (score 2):

You can always make your own format if its, i dont know, just for some school project or something like that (wild guess). Format your data the way you want, for example:

```
X,Y,Z,R,G,B\n
X,Y,Z,R,G,B\n
X,Y,Z,R,G,B\n...
```

for vertices and after you list all your vertices you could use some char like '$' or '%' or something like that which will signify end of vertices and start of indices which will make it easier to parse later. You can assume it is always TriangleList topology but you may also dedicate first line of file to configuration and have int 1 for instance represent that you will use trinagleList and so on...

Hope it helps!

P.S.: Julians answer is better in my opinion, its always good to learn new useful stuff for future projects (like in Bioware :D ), just proposing alternative here.